# Checkbox condition database coldfusion

Tags: javascript, database, coldfusion

What I want to do is:

I have these two list of persons, boys and girls, that came in a loop inside of a database, to people voted for them, but the condition is the just can vote for one girl and one boy. I am trying to do this with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('profile-check');
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 2) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false)
    alert("Allowed only 2 votes.");
    $(this).prop('checked', false).parent().addClass('profile-error')
    //$('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false).parent().removeClass('bgcheck'); }
});
</script>
```

But the result is the people can check for two and this include boy and boy o girl and girl instead of just one boy and a girl.

code:

```
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#dbMarks#">select left(tutgroup,2) as anio,appaterno,apmaterno,nombres,house,codigo,tutgroup   from studentCand 
where (tutgroup like 's4%' or tutgroup like '5B%')
group by left(tutgroup,2),appaterno,apmaterno,nombres,house,codigo,tutgroup
order by left(tutgroup,2) desc,appaterno,apmaterno,nombres
</cfquery>

<div class="container">
<div class="row mtc">
    <cfoutput query="data" group="anio">
    <cfoutput>  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 profile-chart">
            <div class="portrait-settings">
            <img src="http://intranet.markham.edu.pe/istaff2/photos_students/#codigo#.jpg" width="65px">
            </div>          
            <div class="details-chart">     
            <p class="mtc"><strong>#appaterno#</strong>, #nombres#</p>
            <span class="mtc">#anio# - </span>
            <span>#house#</span>
            <span>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="codigos"  value="#appaterno# #apmaterno# #nombres# (#tutgroup#)" required>
            </span>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </cfoutput>  
    </cfoutput>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use a `type= "radio"` checkbox for each group. This will only allow one choice in each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to do what you want, you need to first have a way to tell, from the data set, which students are male (boy) and which ones are female (girl). I cannot tell from your query if there is a field that allows you to do that so I am going to assume that you can get that information through a change in your query. For the sake of this example, I am going to assume that you have a field in your database for the student's gender and that it is called ***gender***.

Once you have a filed that tells you if a student is a boy or a girl, you can then use radio buttons to solve your problem in place of check boxes. Then you will have exactly one value selected for boys and one for girls and you don't need to add any JavaScript validation to enforce it. Here's the code to do this:

```
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#dbMarks#">
  select left(tutgroup,2) as anio, appaterno, apmaterno, nombres, house,
    codigo, tutgroup, gender  
  from studentCand 
  where (tutgroup like 's4%' or tutgroup like '5B%')
  group by left(tutgroup,2),appaterno, apmaterno, nombres, house, codigo, 
    tutgroup, gender
  order by left(tutgroup,2) desc,appaterno,apmaterno,nombres
</cfquery>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mtc">
    <cfoutput query="data" group="anio">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 profile-chart">
        <div class="portrait-settings">
          <img src="http://intranet.markham.edu.pe/istaff2/photos_students/#codigo#.jpg" 
           width="65px">
        </div>          
        <div class="details-chart">     
          <p class="mtc"><strong>#appaterno#</strong>, #nombres#</p>
          <span class="mtc">#anio# - </span>
          <span>#house#</span>
          <span>
           <cfif gender eq 'male'>
            <input  type="radio" name="boy"  value="#appaterno# #apmaterno# #nombres# (#tutgroup#)">
           <cfelse>
            <input  type="radio" name="girl"  value="#appaterno# #apmaterno# #nombres# (#tutgroup#)">
           </cfif>
         </span>
       </div> 
    </div> 
  </cfoutput>  
</div>
</div>
```

Notice that because you have two sets of radio buttons, one named ***boy*** and the other one named ***girl***, you will have exactly one boy and one girl selected at a time.